# Django update on queryset to change ID of ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to update the ids of a bunch of objects and a related table that refers to the objects.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test=models.ForeignKey('Test',db_column='testId')


d={1:2,5:10}

for fr,to in d.items():
    Test.objects.filter(id=fr).update(id=to)
    Question.objects.filter(test_id=fr).update(test_id=to)
```

I have tried `test_id`, `test__id` and `testId` but get this error message:

```
django.db.models.fields.FieldDoesNotExist: Question has no field named 'test_id'
```

Is this currently possible?

Edit: I would prefer not to have to load the `Test` object for each id change.

Comment: And what happens when you try this?

Comment: Sorry, error message now included.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot update ForeignKey field with ID. You should pass the model object to update it. You can try

```
for fr,to in d.items():
    Test.objects.filter(id=fr).update(id=to)
    test_obj = Test.objects.get(id=to)
    Question.objects.filter(test_id=fr).update(test=test_obj)
```

[Refer Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields)

#### Update:

From Django 1.8, you can use `id` of ForeignKey object to update an object.

```
for fr,to in d.items():
    Test.objects.filter(id=fr).update(id=to)
    Question.objects.filter(test_id=fr).update(test_id=to)
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I did to get it done. The doco does describe this method but doesn't explicitly state that you CAN'T do it by ID and since you can set foreign keys on individual models by the ID I thought that there might be a way that I had missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Implemented in Django 1.8

Usage:

```
Bar.objects.filter(pk=foo.id).update(a_id=bar.id)
Bar.objects.filter(pk=foo.id).update(a=bar.id)
```

See [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21144) and [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c21e86ab9e3e5ebd6d245d038cb0cb352cd84c3a).